# elements in an ArrayList

Tags: java

I have been given an algorithm which i have to implement which is doing a breadth first traversal. In the one sections it says `For each car C2 that is adjacent to C Begin` so my question is, how do you use a for loop to find the adjacent elements in that arrayList? the only ways i know of using for loops is the following (which i've tried and it doesn't work). `for(Car C2 : C) {};` and then within that for loop i have to other things.

Comment: Have you tried to use a loop with indexes instead of manupilating Object in ArrayList ?

Comment: Im not sure i get what you mean by that

Comment: Can you tell us more about the Car class? How do you know which cars are adjacent to each other? Do you have an adjacency matrix/list?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be misunderstanding the concept of graph data structures vs a list. You can implement a graph by using an adjacency list(I suspect this is what you mean by "in that arrayList").Each node in the graph will contain a list of adjacent nodes. By definition every node in the adjacency list of the current node is an adjacent node.

Another implementation is an adjacency matrix.

Do some research on graph structures.